# Linq To Entities, Select multiple sets of data with one query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I've found plenty of info on how to select multiple result sets with stored procedures but nothing substantial on how to do so with a linq query.

For example, I can do sub-queries that return mulitple sets of results with something like

```
var query = (from school in context.Schools
             where school.id == someId
             select new
             {
                 subSetA = (from student in context.Students
                            select student).ToList(),
                 subSetB = (from building in context.Buildings
                            select building).ToList(),
             }).First();

query.subSetA;  //Access subSetA
query.subSetB; //Access subSetB
```

Which works fine, but what if I just want to select both subSetA and subSetB without querying against the school table? I want to select two separate sets of data that gets sent to the server in one query.

Any information as to how to do this with EF 6 would be great.

Comment: ...your current `select` already doesn't include `school`?

Comment: @jjj Did you really not understand the question? How do I select subSetA and subSetB without querying against the school table? I'll reword it to not use "select".

Comment: ohhh, you want to load unrelated sets of data with a single query, and you're currently using the query against `Schools` as a dummy query. Sounds like something EF wasn't made to do, so the solution will probably end up being hack-ish...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm sure there are many ways to do this, but if you want to avoid introducing a third `DbSet` into the mix...

```
var query = (from s in context.Students.Take(1)
             select new
             {
                 subSetA = context.Students.ToList(),
                 subSetB = context.Buildings.ToList(),
             })
```

Then, you can use `query.ToList()` or maybe using `query.Load()` and working with `context.Students.Local`, etc. would work.

Comment: This is nice, but you're basically doing what I'm doing except using "Students" as the dummy table instead of "Schools". It's not something I didn't consider, I was just wondering if there was a better way to do this.